# postgresql full text proximity (`<->`) search on json document

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I'm experiencing some unexpected behaviour for certain word combinations trying to use full text search on a json(b) document. Perhaps my understanding of text search is is incorrect or maybe this is a known bug.

Here's a simple example:

```
-- searching on text, expected true, query returned true
select to_tsvector('the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog')             
       @@ to_tsquery('fox <-> jump');
 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 row)

-- searching json, expected true, but query returns false
select to_tsvector('{"example": ["the quick brown fox", "jumped over the lazy dog"]}'::json) 
       @@ to_tsquery('fox <-> jump');
 ?column?
----------
 f
(1 row)
```

The unexpected behaviour seems to only happen across text elements for certain words, for instance, searching for `fox <-> over` works in the following example.

```
-- expected this to be true, and I get true back
select to_tsvector('["jumped the quick brown fox", "over the lazy dog"]'::json) 
       @@ to_tsquery('fox <-> over');
 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

and similarly, if `fox jumped` were in the same text element, then the query returns true, as expected.

```
select to_tsvector('["the quick brown fox jumped", "over the lazy dog"]'::json) 
       @@ to_tsquery('fox <-> jump');
 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

postgresql / system version tested on:

```
select version();
                                                    version
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 10.1 on x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1), 64-bit
(1 row)
```

Comment: "to_tsquery('fox <-> over');" :  'over' is a stop word.  It gets ignored.

Comment: Of course! Don't know why I didn't think of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly why, but PostgreSQL counts a token between the array elements:

```
SELECT to_tsvector('english', jsonb '{"example": ["the quick brown fox", "jumped over the lazy dog"]}');

                      to_tsvector                       
--------------------------------------------------------
 'brown':3 'dog':10 'fox':4 'jump':6 'lazi':9 'quick':2
(1 row)
```

You see that `'fox'` is in position 4, while `'jump'` is in position 6.

This may be a PostgreSQL bug; I was too lazy to debug into it.

Comment: Thanks, this behavior, plus the observation that `over` is a stopword, explains the described behavior. On a sidenote, do you happen to know why `\n` is not ignored in the following `select to_tsvector('hello\nworld')` outputs: `'hello':1 'nworld':2`

Comment: It doesn't explain the behavior to me - `over` comes *after* `jumped`, not before. `\n` is not treated as an escape sequence unless you prefix the string literal with `E` as in `E'hello\nworld'`.

Comment: I used a different text for the 'over' example